# macOS Terminal and Python interruption

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm not sure how easy a problem this will be to replicate, but I consistently run into this issue:

```
>>> result_df.shap^C^C^C
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Basically, I'll attempt to type `result_df.shape` and I'll get "stonewalled" at `result_df.shap`. This isn't exclusive to trying that exact command - this issue does not discriminate. The only way to get back to the `>>>` empty prompt is to mash `Ctrl + C`.

Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Here are some potentially relevant specs:

```
MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016)
macOS High Sierra, 10.13.6
```

Comment: Did someone switch your "e" and "c" keys and are you holding down control? :)

Comment: After typing `result_df.shap`, are you hitting autocomplete (e.g. via the tab key)? It may be that you have a very slow autocomplete system that somehow gets stuck when looking for possible completions of your code.

Comment: @jhansen, Yes, I do use the tab-autocomplete function a lot. That functionality works just fine in my normal shell, but not in the Python shell. But I notice that this issue doesn't exclusively occur when attempting to autocomplete. Sometimes I try typing out `result_df.shape` letter-by-letter and will get stuck in the place described.

Comment: iPython does autocomplition in more convinient way for me. Do you have same results there?

Comment: Have you looked at what your CPU is doing when this happens (check e.g. via `top` command)? Is the Python process just going to sleep or is anything running up to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting input issues:

1. Check that your keyboard is not the issue by typing random words and importantly the commands that gave you trouble, and log the keystrokes. A keyboard tester web site is just a google away (I found [this](http://www.keyboardtester.com/) immediately but can't attest to quality.)
2. Disconnect and reconnect your keyboard.
3. Reproduce the issue on another computer.
4. Edit your SO post showing the repro

If you follow this procedure I think it will help you find the issue!